# EOF in async_read() in boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost-asio, tcpclient

When the async_read_some() returns an exception of EOF does it mean the server stopped sending data or does it mean the connection is closed. I'm having this confusion as I cant find a method to know if the client has received all data from server.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It indicates the connection has closed.  Although documented [elswhere](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/receive/overload1.html) it is still applicable:

> An error code of `boost::asio::error::eof` indicates that the connection was closed by the peer.

If a client needs to know that all data has been received from the server, then consider supporting framing in the communication protocol.  Boost.Asio provides higher-level operations to help make this easier.  For example [async_read_until()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until.html) can be used on protocols where a certain set of characters are used to indicate the end of a message, and [async_read()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read.html) can be used for either fixed-length protocols or variable length protocols with a fixed length header.